# Xcode error - OpenFrameworks example projects giving 'Use of undeclared identifier Error'

Tags: xcode, opengl, macos-catalina, openframeworks

I am trying to run any of unaltered OpenFramworks examples on Xcode that are available from their website
https://openframeworks.cc/download/  and they all give me the a list of similar errors, all related to GL:

```
  use of undeclared identifier 'GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB'
            textureTarget = GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB;
                            ^

  use of undeclared identifier 'GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB'
bNormalized = (inTexture.getTextureData().textureTarget!=GL_TEXTURE_...
                                                         ^
```

I haven't altered any projects and running ALL of them reproduce the same errors.. What can I do to solve this?

- Unrelated, but might be related - I previously brew installed GLFW, GLEW and GLM using homebrew because I'm learning OpenGL.. does this matter?

[image: list of errors - Xcode]

Comment: You should be using the brew installed versions of glew and glfw3, and linking the respective dylibs (As well as OpenGL.framework). glm is a header only library, so you can just include it.

Comment: I actually tried linking the dylibs in Xcode and thought it would work but it didn't.